# Build error with GPU support when building pip

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I've reached the [Setting up TensorFlow for Development](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#setting-up-tensorflow-for-development) section of the Tensorflow 0.9 tutorial, and I'm getting an error when trying to add support for GPU.

```
\> bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

> ERROR: /home/.../tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:1489:1:
>   undeclared inclusion(s) in rule
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:batchtospace_op_gpu': this rule is missing
>   dependency declarations for the following files included by
>   'tensorflow/core/kernels/batchtospace_op_gpu.cu.cc'

I do not get this error if I exclude the `--config=cuda` directive, however.

Setup:
Elementary OS 0.3
tensorflow 0.9
cuda-7.5
cudnn 5.0.5
gcc 4.8.4

Answer (score 0):

try adding

`cxx_builtin_include_directory: "/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include"`

to

`third_party/gpus/crosstool/CROSSTOOL`

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3431